magento 2.4.6 the requested company is not found
I am trying to edit companies using the "Edit" link at the right of the grid of companies from the admin.
some companies when i try to edit it's getting an exception thrown.

The requested company is not found


check your logs you will have extra info that can help you debug issue here

No errors in the log files.
